# drupal views more link

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, drupal-views

i'm new to drupal views. **More link** not displayed with my view block. i set more link both *Create more lin*k and *Always display more link* option too. Find picture below for view settings.

[image]

Note: i'm sure there is around 10+ nodes available to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  have only block display, so where should go "More"? :) Create also "Page" display.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific page to link on more then you can use header or footer also
1. Add Global Custom Text in Header or Footer
2. Put Your Link There.
That is alternate way for more link